# What is the procedure for handling poor quality tags created by users?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

[This question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5586/how-to-design-and-install-full-length-floor-to-ceiling-built-in-bookcase) added two new tags "tight" and "squeeze".  I believe that these are not helpful categories and edited the question to remove them. They are however still in the list of optional for tags use on the site which may lead others to use them simply because they are there.  Can moderators remove such tags from the site if they believe they are not helpful?  Is there a procedure for experienced users to vote on them?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they have been removed. Removing unhelpful/unclear tags from questions and/or bringing them up for discussion on meta is exactly the right process.

Comment: I think that there's a nightly script that runs that checks if any tags are not assigned, and deletes them. That explains why they showed up initially but now are no longer available.